# Select box does not update v-model

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I got a little problem that I'm unable to solve. I created a select box like this https://codepen.io/spqrinc/pen/wvaqrPj

```
<div id="app">
  Selected value: {{item.picked}}
  <hr />
<select v-model="item.picked">
  <option v-for="(item, index) in item.values" :value="item.value" :key="index">{{item.value}} - {{item.title}}</option>
</select>
</div>
```

This is working (as you can see on the example).

Now I included `vue-router` and added this:

```
  beforeRouteEnter (to, _from, next) {
            let querypath = `/path/to/api`;

            next (vm => {
                vm.$wait.start ('loading');
                axios
                .get (querypath).then ((resp) => {
                    vm.item = resp.data.data;
                    vm.item.picked = 1;
                    vm.$wait.end ('loading');
                });
            });
        },
```

Now the first value is automatically selected. But if I select an other value, the v-model is not updated. `Selected value:` always shows `1`.

Why is this the case?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item.picked` is not reactive in `Selected value: {{item.picked}}` so it only reads the initial value on mount.

To clarify one of your points, the v-model is being updated, but the display is not.

To fix this use a computed property which returns `item.picked`.

e.g.

- Refactor `Selected value: {{item.picked}}` to `Selected value: {{pickedItem}}`
- Add a computed property of `pickedItem`

```js
computed: {
    pickedItem() {
      return this.item.picked;
    }
  }
```